# XSD one element value must be greater than another?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Im very new to XML and i cant figure out how can I restrict one element to be always higher than another one. Here is the code

```
<xs:element name="limit" type="xs:integer"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="enrolled">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

How can I say, that element limit will be always higher than enrolled ( limit > enrolled ) ? I will be thankful for every help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

Use an `xs:assert` on an ancestor element containing both `limit` and `enrolled`, e.g:

```
<xs:assert test="limit > enrolled"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

**in altova xmlspy, it needs to be...(also with some context):**

```
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Weather">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="temp" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                    <xs:element name="tempmax" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                </xs:all>
                                <xs:attribute name="dateTime" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                <xs:assert test="temp le tempmax"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
```